Trying to disable existing conditional access policy using cli
I am undergrad fellow, new to Azure Environment, working on one project main aim is to disable existing conditional access policy basically it is task to our batch, while searching on internet I found one post of Stack overflow somehow related to it Delete policy using Microsoft Graph Powershell. But it looks like it is done by PowerShell, and I'm trying with CLI. Thanks in advance.


Trying to disable existing conditional access policy using cli

There is no direct command to delete a Conditional access policy using Azure CLI. Alternatively, you can use Microsoft Graph Explorer to remove the existing conditional access policy.
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies/{id}

In my environment, I need to delete one conditional access policy with the name samplepolicy1.
Portal:

You can run the above query in Azure CLI using the az rest method like below:
Command:
access_token=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://graph.microsoft.com --query accessToken -o tsv)

# Get the ID of the Conditional Access policy
az rest --method Delete --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/conditionalAccess/policies/8xxx62a-e0cdxxxxfaff8e3 --headers "Content-Type=application/json" "Authorization=Bearer $access_token" -o tsv


The above command executed and removed a conditional policy successfully.
Reference:
Delete conditionalAccessPolicy - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn
